# Covering a Polygon with circles with a constant radius of $r$

Tags: geometry, optimization, computational-geometry

"I am currently engaged in optimizing the placement of sensors in an agricultural field, inspired by the problem outlined in the paper '[Approximation Algorithms for Robot Tours in Random Fields with Guaranteed Estimation Accuracy](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2210.08107)'.

The specific challenge I'm facing involves efficiently covering a convex polygon with circles of a constant radius $r$ (where the circle's area is always smaller than the polygon's). In my pursuit of a solution, I've encountered the algorithm proposed by Shai Gul in the paper '[Efficient covering of convex domains by congruent discs](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2108.00707),' but its complexity poses implementation challenges.

Considering the NP-Hard nature of the problem, I am actively seeking alternative algorithms with worse approximations that may be more manageable for implementation.

Thank you in advance for any guidance or assistance.

Comment: How large are the circles wrt the polygon ?

Comment: See my comment on the answer from @CyeWaldman

Comment: See "Efficient Maximal Poisson-Disk Sampling" at https://www.sandia.gov/-samitch/scott-a-mitchell/publications/papers-2007/ and https://doi.org/10.1145/2010324.1964944

Comment: Please see my comment to @EthanBolker following my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would attack this problem. First, ask yourself if the circles are to be overlapping, so as to leave no part of the polygon area uncovered, or just tangent to each other with uncovered deltoid spaces in between.

Then, find the centroid of the polygon and place a circle of the specified radius there. If the circles are to overlap, inscribe a regular hexagon in the circle, Otherwise, circumscribe the circle with the hexagon.

Now, build out a honeycomb with concentric rings of hexagons, so as to fill in the polygon. Finally, fill in the circles (inscribed are circumscribed) centered on each hexagon.

Comment: +1 The paper linked by the OP in fact uses such a grid of hexagons. The optimality then depends on finding the best center and orientation for the grid. It's possible that a few experiments making small changes to the center and stepping through orientations at, say, 10 degree intervals of rotation could lower the number of circles enough to come close enough to the optimum for the OPs practical purpose.

Comment: @EthanBolker That's a good point because fitting a hexagon array to an arbitrary shape could be difficult. It's really dependent on the size of the circles relative to host polygon to determine if the extra effort is worthwhile. As with many problems, you have to weigh the effort against the gain achieved. At any rate, what you suggest is relatively easy with software that can determine if one polygon is inside, overlaps, or outside of another.

Comment: @EthanBolker Just wanted to let you know that I developed a full-fledged program to do such calculations, paying particular attention to your concerns about orientation and displacement. I was surprised at how much difference small changes could make.

Comment: Thanks for the update.